# Lanzar Ventana desde segundo plano Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intentservice

estoy tratando de lanzar una ventana cuando se ejecuta una acción sobre mi app , El problema esquema esta aveces puede estar ejecutadonse en segundo plano por lo cual aveces la tendré que lanzar sin una actividad:

Estoy ejecutando este fragmento:

```
public void alertaSubscriptor(String titulo,String mensaje) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) MOCA.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MOCA.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ventanaemrgente, null);
        myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "touch me");
                wm.removeViewImmediate(v);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Add layout to window manager
        wm.addView(myView, params);

    }
```

Pero en segundo plano no se ejecuta

> 02-16 09:33:07.140 31071-32472/com.procibernetica.moca W/MessageQueue:
>   Handler (android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler) {21c0847c} sending
>   message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler
>   (android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler) {21c0847c} sending message
>   to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:336)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.onVsync(Choreographer.java:751)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.dispatchVsync(DisplayEventReceiver.java:139)
>                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
>                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Como podría lanzar una ventana o una burbuja como messenger , cuando la actividad esta en segundo plano?

Answer (score 1):

Es la idea del segundo plano que actividades con gui no se ejecutan. Para tener ejecución de código en el fondo, se usa un [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Si quieres que tu servicio sigue ejecutandose en el fondo, tienes que implementarlo con:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Service.START_STICKY avisa al sistema de no parar el servicio cuando la app termina.

Comment: Y si ya lo tengo corriendo sobre un servicio ? , como podría llamar una actividad?

Comment: Usando un `Intent` igual que como desde otra actividad. Si agregas el flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` al intent, te llama `onNewIntent()` en caso que ya existe la actividad.

Answer (score 1):

Lanzar una ventana en segundo plano como un diálogo no sería algo útil ya que en realidad no sería visible, para este caso lo ideal es validar si se muestra o no un diálogo:

```
private static boolean isForeground;

@Override
    protected void onResume() { 
        isForeground = true; //app regresa de background.
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        foreground = false; //App en background.
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Por medio de los métodos `onResume()` y `onPause()`, puedes determinar si esta en foreground o background y mediante esto mostrar el dialogo.

```
if (isForeground) {
    // Muestra dialogo.
}
```

Si deseas una notificación que se pueda lanzar cuando tu Activity esta en Background, puede ser una push notification o un Toast, incluso una vista como la que comentas pero es importante tener el contexto. Si la notificación se envía desde un servicio, el contexto en realidad sería el servicio.